# Demerera sugar vs. brown sugar

Tags: sugar

Some recipes I have seen call for demerera sugar, rather than what I would normally use, which is brown sugar. Is there a noticeable difference in taste or outcome, or this likely to be somewhat of a marketing influence? Is it related to country of origin? How is demerera sugar different to other sugar forms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Demerara sugar is a sugar made from reduced, crystallized cane juice.  That is, it is a form of brown sugar with the molasses left in during the refining process.

Regular brown sugar is actually made from pure white sugar, with molasses added back in for flavor.

They will have similar performance and flavor profiles so you can substitute freely, although demerara sugar may have less of a pronounced molasses flavor.  Your best substitute is light brown sugar.

Comment: +1 Clear and concise. Thanks. So, perhaps easier to manufacture, but more expensive through economies of scale? Because it is quite a bit more expensive and harder to source where I am.

Comment: I imagine price difference *is* economy of scale and distribution, but that is just speculation...

Comment: Is there a difference is moisture levels?