# No Demerara sugar

Tags: baking, sugar, pie, brown-sugar

I have just made an apple pie with a crumble topping for friends coming to lunch.  The recipe specified Demerara sugar but I had run out so used dark soft brown instead.  I think soft has more moisture in it.  Will swapping sugars be a problem in the crumble topping? What differences should I expect?

Comment: I usually make my crumble with a mix of  2/3 caster and 1/3 soft brown sugar - i don't personally like the crunch of Demerara  sugar-crystals... yours would taste a little more toffee-like than mine, but this is a matter of taste, so not an answer. It won't be 'horrible'.. :)

Comment: Hi @KateBatlin.  The question as written will probably be closed, because whether or not it will be "horrible" is a matter of opinion.  I would suggest altering the question so that you are asking for a replacement for demerara sugar.

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/39508/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/42496/67 .  And in my experience, it's pretty difficult to mess up a crumble topping

Comment: Thank you!  It was actually quite nice - thank you for taking the time to help x

Comment: @RobinBetts after the edit, I think your comment is actually a starting point for a nice answer.